# How to add date field in Spring MVC

Tags: java, binding, spring-mvc

If i want to use custom date editor i need few things to ask

```
1)In database do i have to set variable startDate as datetime or varchar
2)IN Person class startDate is refered as Date or String
```

I have controller like this

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
          }
```

in jsp form i have

```
<td><form:label path="startDate">date</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="startdate"/></td>
```

But when i submit form , nothing happens

this is the other methods in controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAdd(Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show add page");

        // Create new Person and add to model
        // This is the formBackingOBject
        model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new Person());

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addpage.jsp
        return "hibernate/addpage";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid @ModelAttribute("personAttribute") Person person, BindingResult result) {
        logger.debug("Received request to add new person");

        if (result.hasErrors()) 
        return "hibernate/addpage";
        else
        personService.add(person);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addedpage.jsp
        return "hibernate/addedpage";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime and Date. The Binder to convert a string to Date also looks fine as long as your input is in the dd-MM-yyyy format. Your controller has no methods though. Did you post all of your code? Do you have a form:method tag?

Comment: i haven't used form:method tag , why is it used for. i have added the code in ques

Comment: Well somewhere in your jsp you need to specify what method of the Controller should be called.